# SSRS Mutli parameter had commas in it, how do i pass them without commas

Tags: t-sql, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a multiselect list parameter and two of the options have commas in them, well SSRS passes parameters with commas in it so its not registering the right value for it. how do i go around this?

multi list parameter examples-
option1, this is option one.
option2, this is option two, 2.
option three.
option four.

right now i have my code set up where i have  WHEN Field in (@Param split string function that splits on commas).

i added this where clause and it helped show results from the parameter value with the commas,

```
 Where ([Param]) collate database_default IN(SELECT Value FROM dbo.FnSplit(@Param,';'))
```

but now i cannot select more than one parameter at a time because i get an error message

```
 An Error Occurred During Local Report Processing.
 An Error has occurred during report porcessing.
 Cannot Read the next data row for the dataset Dataset1.
 String or binary data would be truncated.
```

Any clues as to whats my next step?

Comment: It should be passing the values inside the string delimiters. I don't understand why this is breaking.

Comment: Maybe it's a typo in the question but you're splitting on semi-colon `;` not comma `,` ...

Comment: Yes, I changed it to semi-colon because two of my parameter values have commas in them and therefore don't work when i split on commas.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to use a string split. Just use:
WHERE Value IN (@Param)

SQL Server will handle the commas automatically.

Comment: Thats the first thing i tried, like i said in my original post two of the values for the dropdown have commas within them so they get split in half and the results don't come back.

Comment: You said you tried "WHEN Field in (@Param split string function that splits on commas)".  I assumed that meant you were doing something like this "WHERE Field IN(SELECT Value FROM dbo.FnSplit(@Param,','))". Do you mean you're already doing this "WHERE Value IN (@Param)"?

Comment: Yeah the When should be Where, I was doing WHERE Field IN(SELECT Value FROM dbo.FnSplit(@Param,',')) because Where Value IN (@Param) did not work.